# Reading and assigning variables from property file in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, grep, ksh

Im looking to read property file in a shell script and use them accordingly

below is my scenerio

sample proeprty file:

```
Dom=hello1,hello2,hello3,hello4,hello5
path=/u01/app/export/domains
```

i want to read Dom and path variables from this file in a shell script
and use it in while/for loop to perform operations

like below:

```
while IFS =, read read <hello1 ..hello2..hellon>  -- in a loop
do
{
some operations here
//will use path variable in this loop for all iterations.
}
done <sample.properties
```

---then iterate the loop with hello2 and so on until end of comma separated strings for variable Dom

searched old posts but could not match my scenerio...please help me out

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it should be `while IFS="=,"` so you use both `=` and `,` as separators.

Comment: Thankyou @Barmar how about the vaiaable path..how to iterate in a loop?

Comment: Did you read the linked question? It shows how to set the variables in a loop.

Comment: You can `source` the properties resulting in variables `${Dom}` and `${path}` and use these.

Comment: Thankyou @WalterA i figured it out later..yes i sourced it...